# why list items in output are repetitive?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, web-scraping

i have a list named events and loop over it via for loop
through each iteration i update the values of dict and then append it to the list.
so i desire that list items dont be repetitive and be different.
[image: code:]

[image: output:]

i tested that if i put the dict definition into the for loop, it will be fixed.
but my question is why it doesn't work when dict definition is out of the for loop?

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.python.org/events/python-events/'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

events = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'list-recent-events'}).findAll('li')

events_list = []
events_dict = dict()

for event in events:
    events_dict['name'] = event.find('h3').find("a").text
    events_dict['location'] = event.find('span', {'class': 'event-location'}).text
    events_dict['time'] = event.find('time').text
    events_list.append(events_dict)

for items in events_list:
    print(items)
```

Comment: "but my question is why it doesn't work when dict definition is out of the for loop?" Because you're updating a single dict and putting that same object in the list multiple times.

Comment: through each iteration i change the dict values and immediately after that i append it to the list.
so the appended values should be different not the same

Comment: You change dict values in the _same dict_. `.append()` doesn't copy the dict.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you overwrite the content of `dict` with every iteration if it is outside the loop but in `list` it is only a reference and not a new `dict`. If you move it into the loop it will work, cause it is focused to each iteartion and become a separat/individual `dict`:

```
for event in events:
    events_dict = dict()
    events_dict['name'] = event.find('h3').find("a").text
    events_dict['location'] = event.find('span', {'class': 'event-location'}).text
    events_dict['time'] = event.find('time').text
    events_list.append(events_dict)
```

##### Example

However you could also simplify your code a bit:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.python.org/events/python-events/'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

events = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'list-recent-events'}).find_all('li')

events_list = []

for event in events:
    events_list.append({
        'name': event.h3.text,
        'location': event.find('span', {'class': 'event-location'}).text,
        'time': event.find('time').text,
    })

for items in events_list:
    print(items)
```

Comment: You might want to also explain why this works better.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but my question is why I can't add the dictionary with different values after that I make it

Comment: I override the dict values, not the list items.I mean immediatly after assigning new values to dict I append them to the list. 
so I desire that list items don't override

Comment: As mentioned, sorry I am not that fast in typing :), the "values" in your `list` are just references to the `events_dict`  outside - if its value change, so the value in all references in your list will change. This will not happen, if you create a new instance in each iteration.

Comment: thanks a lot.
if the values in the list be just references to the `events_dict`, so why when i `del` this dict, list items doesn't change:

`del events_dict`
`for items in events_list:`
    `print(items)`

Comment: I mean if list items are connected to dict by references, why can we have list correctly after deleting dict?

Comment: May take a read to deep dive: https://medium.com/swlh/a-deep-dive-into-variables-in-python-8f55f69c3653

Answer (score 0):

the answer is related to the topic of cloning objects (shallow copy and deep copy):
Assignment statements in python do not create copies of objects, they only bind names to an object.
for immutable objects, that usually don't make a difference.
but for working with mutable objects (like the dict used here) the assignments statement only creates shallow copies

so the code fixed after using `deepcopy` method:

[image: fixed code:]

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import copy

url = 'https://www.python.org/events/python-events/'
req = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')

events = soup.find('ul', {'class': 'list-recent-events'}).findAll('li')

events_list = []
events_dict = dict()


for event in events:
    events_dict['name'] = event.find('h3').find("a").text
    events_dict['location'] = event.find('span', {'class': 'event-location'}).text
    events_dict['time'] = event.find('time').text
    events_list.append(copy.deepcopy(events_dict))

for items in events_list:
    print(items)
```

Comment: Before using `deepcopy` method you should import `copy`